# understanding PHP POST and how to submit multiple commands

Tags: php, html

I have a growing amount of code in my page.  Individually, I have an okay understanding of how all the various pieces work, but I don't understand how they function TOGETHER.  The first bit of code I have pulls a name from an SQL database, then passes it into another table, sorting that table by the name I've chosen:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table id="" summary="PAGE HEADER" style='width:20%'>
<tr> 
  <th>
  <?php
    include('./db.php');
    $PM = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT PMName FROM report ORDER BY PMName ASC");
  ?> 
    <b style="font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, Optima, Arial, sans-serif;">Choose PM: </b>
    <br> 
    <span class="custom-dropdown custom-dropdown--red">    
    <Select class="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--red" name="PMName" onChange="submit(this.form)"<> 
  <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($PM)) {
    $selected = array_key_exists('PMName', $_POST) && $_POST['PMName'] == $row[0] ? ' selected' : '';
    $sel = ($table === $row[0]) ? "id='sel' selected" : "";
    printf(" <option value='%s' %s>%s</option>\n", $row[0], $selected, $row[0]);
    }
  ?>  
  </th>
</span>
</tr>
</select>    
</form>
```

Because the results are huge, I've built in a sort of "previous page, next page" deal so the user can display only 10 results at a time.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
$postedLimit = (isset($_POST['next']) ? (int) $_POST['next'] : 0);
$nextLimit = $postedLimit + 10;
session_start();
$_SESSION['page'] = ((int) $nextLimit / 10)+1;
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM report WHERE PMName = '$PMSelection' AND REGNSB <> 0.000 ORDER BY RegNSB DESC Limit $nextLimit,$LimitItems");
}
?>

<table id="box-table-a" stlye="widgth:20%">
<form method="POST" action="">
<div class="container">
<div class="right">Page <?= $_SESSION['page'] ?> of <?= $totalPages ?>   
<input type="submit" name="next" value="next" onclick="this.value=<?php echo $nextLimit; ?>">
</div></form></div></table>
```

My issue is that when I click this "next" button, this query is run:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM report WHERE PMName = '$PMSelection' AND REGNSB <> 0.000 ORDER BY RegNSB DESC Limit $nextLimit,$LimitItems");
```

but, (forgive my non-understanding of how this whole thing works...) $PMSelection is now empty, and is not passing any value to the SQL query, so whatever name I had the list filtered by goes away. I come from the world of VBA, where once I define something, I can use it forever... why $PMSelection HAS a value at one point and then DOESN'T have a value later on is very confusing to me....

My questions are these:

1. Why is $PMSelection, once defined and previously used, not still available later on when I try to use it?
2. How do I make it so that $PMSelection is HELD somewhere/somehow so I can access it in this second bit of code?

Comment: If you do `$PMSelection = 'whatever'` then you execute the page, that value is set for the life of that page. If you go to a new page, if that value is not reassigned, then it does not exist. This is why we have `$_SESSION` in php for instance, as it allows you to store reference to a value in a global way.

Answer (score 0):

On your first page where you have the variable `$PMSelection` filled put in into your `$_SESSION` like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['PMName'])) {
    $_SESSION['PMSelection'] = $_POST['PMName'];
}
```

And the second page, if it is called later, can get this value back like this:

```
$PMSelection = $_SESSION['PMSelection'];
```

You can do this with all your data.

**Another way**

If the `<form>` element of the first page would send it's data to the second page on submitting it, then you would get all input field data in the `$_POST` array when second page is called. But you have to change your `<form>` tag like this:

```
<form action="second_page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And if there is no input element with this data in your form, and the data is not sensitive you can make a hidden input field and put your data in it, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="PMSelection" value="{value}" /><!-- single data -->

<input type="hidden" name="PMSelection[]" value="{value1}" /><!-- array data -->
<input type="hidden" name="PMSelection[]" value="{value2}" />
<input type="hidden" name="PMSelection[]" value="{value2}" />
[...]
```

Comment: I guess I was not clear - there isn't any actual second page.  When the user clicks "previous" or "next", I execute this command into the table:

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM report WHERE     PMName = '$PMSelection' AND REGNSB <> 0.000 ORDER BY RegNSB DESC Limit $nextLimit,$LimitItems");    

the $nextLimit and $LimitItems shows them SQL entires 0-10, then 10-20, then 20-30, etc. However, when I click the next button, the value or $PMSelection resets....

Comment: @lordterrin I can not see it in your example code. Where do you use the variable for the second time and how? Another thing is, that I cannot see where `$PMSelection` comes from...

Comment: @lordterrin Another thing is, that you don't need two pages to use `$_SESSION`. You also can use it in one page. On first occurence of `$PMSelection` put it in the session and later get it back.

Comment: I was just going to address this.... up at the very top of my page I have

    `$PMSelection = $_POST["PMName"] ;`
    `'printf(" PMSelection: %s ", $PMSelection);'`

From what you suggested, and what I read on w3schools, I put

`<?php session_start(); ?>`

into the page, then ABOVE the code I pasted in my original question I put: `$_SESSION['PMSelection'] = $_POST["PMName"];`

Later on I put : `$PMSelection = $_SESSION['PMSelection'] ;`

but the name still resets back when I click the next button.

Comment: When you click the next button it reloads your page, right? Should this be so? I ask that because you have also an `onclick` handler on this button. `$_POST['PMName']` is filled if you open this page, but is it also filled if you reload your page? Change you session aasignment to `if (!empty($_POST['PMName']) { $_SESSION['PMSelection'] = $_POST['PMName']; }`. So you write it only in session if it's filled... I updated my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SESSION` if you want to use it on different pages or in second bit of code in your language once you store value in session then you'll be able to use it.